# Downloading Yahoo stock prices in R - date setting

Tags: r, yahoo-finance, stock

I am downloading data on stocks from yahoo finance with tseries package. The issue is that I am not getting the most recent date - last price is always for 2 days ago.
Below is my code, can you please advise what I should correct to get all the available prices?

Thank you!

```
`dir <- "D:/Yahoo stock prices"  #location
setwd(dir)

# Packages needed
require(tseries)
require(zoo)

YH <- read.csv2(file="SBI.csv",header=T, sep=";", dec=".")
date <- "2012-09-20"

penny_stocks <- c("SMDS.L", "MNDI.L", "SKG.L")

prices <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(YH[,1])){
    prices <- try(get.hist.quote(as.character(YH[i,1]),
                                 start=date,
                                 quote='Open'
                                 )
                  ,silent=TRUE
    )
    if(!is.character(prices)){
      if(as.character(YH[i,1]) %in% penny_stocks) prices <- prices / 100

      prices <- as.data.frame(prices)
      prices <- cbind(rownames(prices),prices)
      colnames(prices) <- c("date",as.character(YH[i,1]))

      if(length(prices) > 1){
        if(i == 1){
            allprices <- prices
            names <- c("date",as.character(YH[i,1]))
          } else {

            names <- append(colnames(allprices),as.character(YH[i,1]))
            allprices <- merge(allprices,prices,by ="date", all.x = TRUE)
            colnames(allprices) <- names
          }      
      }
    }

}

write.csv2(allprices,"Prices 200511.csv")
warnings()
```

`

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Provide your data with `dput(data)`, this will increase the chances of getting help

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing, the data available on the yahoo site is until the 2020-05-12. You need to specify the end date as by default in tseries, the end is defined as `Sys.Date() - 1`. So using `tseries::get.hist.quote("SMDS.L", end = Sys.Date(), quote = "Open")` will return the data until 2020-05-12. Now you would expect that the default would be good enough, but there are a lot of issues with the yahoo data and getting the correct last records if the data is not located in the US. There probably is a process in place that loads the data a day after closing.

Note that the default settings of `tseries::get.hist.quote` are slightly different than the defaults of underlying function call to `quantmod::getSymbols`. tseries uses the default `Sys.Date() - 1`, quantmod uses Sys.Date(). Also the start dates are different. tseries uses "1991-01-02" as the start date, quantmod uses "2007-01-01".